# Comments box for facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

Is it possible to link a Comments Box to a (public) post on facebook?

I've tried several urls for the Comments Box:

- graph.facebook.com/postid
- permalink
- facebook.com/user/posts/postid

none of them worked.

I know I could use the Graph API to `get` and `post` comments on the users behalf, but that requires the user to accept my application (which seems a bit like an overkill, just for commenting a post in facebook).

Comment: It's not overkill because your application would be **posting content on behalf of the user**.  This is an action that **must** require permissions from the user...

Comment: Yeah, I know that, thats my point. From a users viewpoint, a comments box does exactly the same. No user will ever accept such extended permissions just to comment something when on other sites the comments box does it "for free"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments plugin are for outside (of Facebook) URLs only. It is not possible to use the plugin for public posts on Facebook.

Comment: is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I don't think it is documented - but you can test it by trying to feed the comments plugin with a perma-link to the post... It doesn't work...

Comment: Just because they did not  categorically document that you can't do this - doesn't mean that there is a way...

Comment: @Lix Just wanted to be sure, since I got to tell this to my client. (already tried permalink, see my question)

Comment: @rom - I understand.  Be sure to remind them that by creating an application on a 3rd party platform, they are at the mercy of Facebook.

Comment: @Lix I will, the whole project is at the mercy of facebook, since this is where the content comes from.

Comment: `Comments Box is a social plugin that enables user commenting on your site. Features include moderation tools and distribution.` <= That basically says for enabling social interactions outside of Facebook not within. @Roman If they said Facebook pages or posts it would be explicitly documented.